# Upgrade of Install4j causes LogonUser to fail silently

Tags: install4j

I have a form that collects Windows user credentials.  Then in a validation expression I have the following code:

```
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference phUser = new com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
boolean isValid = com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser(username, domain, password, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, phUser);
```

This validated a Windows user correctly when compiled in Install4J version 6.0.4.  When I upgraded to 6.1.3 it seemed to fail silently.  Wrapping with a try-catch does not catch an Exception; nor does it execute any code after the second line.  I was able to see that the first line succeeded, so at least some JNA is working.  Any thoughts on how to debug or resolve the problem?

I don't really want to go back to a previous version of Install4J; at the very least reverting would not be a viable long-term option.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail silently"? Either the second line throws an error (try to catch Throwable) or it assigns a boolean valid to isValid.

Comment: I was just catching Exception.  Throwable was caught, and indicated that it could not find Advapi32.dll.  Did the older version of install4j automatically include the Window's path, and the newer version not?

Comment: I don't know how JNA loads its libraries. Can you load the DLL explicitly beforehand?